# Returning a reference to the calling object (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, this, pass-by-reference

Having a bit of a hard time understanding this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    private:
      int x;
      int y;
    public:
      Test(int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
      Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
      Test &setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
      void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
      Test obj1(5, 5);

      // Chained function calls.  All calls modify the same object
      // as the same object is returned by reference
      obj1.setX(10).setY(20);

      obj1.print();
      return 0;
}
```

Why would we have to return "*this" as a reference instead of just returning "*this"?

Comment: Do you mean "Why would we have to return `*this` as a reference instead of just returning `*this` *as a value*? If so, because one returns a reference to keep modifying properties of the original object, and not a copy of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `setX` were changed to

```
Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
```

then it returns a *copy* of `*this` instead of a reference to it.  So in

```
obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
```

the `setY` is called on the copy, and not on `obj1` itself.  The copy is discarded and `obj1.y` is never modified from its initial value of 5.